# Oracle SQL: receive ID of grouped foreign key with smallest Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table given.

I need the ID of each BID with the smallest MODIFIED date

| ID | BID | MODIFIED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2020 |
| 2 | 1 | 01.07.2020 |
| 3 | 2 | 04.08.2020 |
| 4 | 2 | 04.06.2020 |
| 5 | 2 | 01.07.2020 |
| 6 | 2 | 01.10.2020 |
| 7 | 3 | 01.09.2020 |

Desired output:

| ID | BID | MODIFIED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2020 |
| 4 | 2 | 04.06.2020 |
| 7 | 3 | 01.09.2020 |

so far, I can get a list of BIDs with the smallest MODIFIED date, but not the ID from it:

```sql
select BID, min(MODIFIED) from MY_TABLE group by BID
```

how can I receive the ID, however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a "first" aggregation function, which uses the `keep` syntax:

```
select BID, min(MODIFIED),
       min(id) keep (dense_rank first over order by modified) as id
from MY_TABLE
group by BID;
```

A common alternative uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bid order by modified asc) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```